# Why are results different between using threads and processes?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, process

When I practiced python's thread and process, I found that the print result of thread and process will be different when processing some functions. I don’t really understand the reason, so I sent the code and the print result together. And how to make the results of the process part and the thread part the same?

When using thread, the thing is all right:

```
import os, time, random, threading, multiprocessing

list = ['python', 'django', 'tornado', 'flask', 'bs5', 'requests', 'uvloop']

new_lists = []

def work():
    if len(list) == 0:
        return
    data = random.choice(list)
    list.remove(data)
    new_data = '%s_new' % data
    new_lists.append(new_data)
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    print('old list lenc is %s' % len(list))

    for i in range(len(list)):
        t = threading.Thread(target=work)
        t.start()
    t.join()

    print('old list:', list)
    print('new list', new_lists, len(new_lists))
    print('time is %s' % (time.time() - start))
```

Which will print: (the result is fine)

```
old list lenc is 7
old list: []
new list ['uvloop_new', 'python_new', 'bs5_new', 'tornado_new', 'django_new', 'requests_new', 'flask_new'] 7
time is 1.0153822898864746
```

But, when change thread to the process, the error happened:

```
import os, time, random, threading, multiprocessing

list = ['python', 'django', 'tornado', 'flask', 'bs5', 'requests', 'uvloop']

new_lists = []


def work():
    if len(list) == 0:
        return
    data = random.choice(list)
    list.remove(data)
    new_data = '%s_new' % data
    new_lists.append(new_data)
    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    print('old list lenc is %s' % len(list))

    for i in range(len(list)):
        t = multiprocessing.Process(target=work)
        t.start()
    t.join()

    print('old list:', list)
    print('new list', new_lists, len(new_lists))
    print('time is %s' % (time.time() - start))
```

Which will print: (The results are not as expected)

```
old list lenc is 7
old list: ['python', 'django', 'tornado', 'flask', 'bs5', 'requests', 'uvloop']
new list [] 0
time is 1.4266910552978516
```

Comment: Every process has its own variables. So you have 8 version of `new_lists` and one in the main process never gets changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In multithread you have shared memory but in multiprocessing, you dont have shared memory. So when you try change global variable in each process, you miss data.
This problem have no solution in this way, you should choose right option attention to your project situations. If you need to manipulate shared data in each parallel function you should use thread.
Although you can use Queue to pass data between each process in multiprocessing.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html